# Sum a List of Objects in Scala

Tags: scala

Here's how I have my models set up:

```
case class Game(id: Long)
case class GamePlayer(id: Long, gameId: Long, points: BigDecimal)
```

I would like to get the sum of all the Game's players' points. So here's what I tried:

```
val pointTotal = allGames.toSeq.map(allGamePlayers(_.id).map(_.points)).sum
```

How would I get this to work in Scala?

Comment: What is the type of `allGames` and the signature of `allGamePlayers()`? and should `allGamePlayers()` really take a function as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val pointTotal = allGames.flatMap((g: Game) => allGamePlayers(g.id).map(_.points)).sum
```

you could also use a list comprehension:

```
val pointTotal = (for(game <- allGames;
                     player <- allGamePlayers(game.id)
                 ) yield player.points).sum
```

Comment: This seemed like it would work but I'm still getting the same error: `missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.id)`

Comment: @Jon - I've updated the answer, it appears to work if you specify the type of `Game`.

Answer (score 2):

Guessing here, as you didn't specify some types:

```
val pointTotal = (
  allGames flatMap {
    game => allGamePlayers(game.id) map (_.points)
  }
).sum
```

note that `game` must be specified explicitly, otherwise the compiler thinks you're trying to pass a lambda to `allGamePlayers`